# How to check if the finger is touching area where object instance exist?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, tango

There is a way to place objects on the surface by swiping finger over the screen (thanks to **@ryemoss** for an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375087/how-to-place-objects-by-swipe-your-finger-across-the-screen/45375182#45375182) )

The question now is how to avoid placing objects on top of each other - **how can we check if the finger is touching the area where there is already an object instance exist**, and place new objects only if the area is empty?

The answer I'm looking for should include the possibility to make objects overlap a bit if needed (touch each other's borders).

Comment: You can perform a raycast https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html    : the hit point can gives you infos such as the kind of objects hitten by the ray - including kittens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from Unity Samples in the SDK ([check here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/AreaLearning/Scripts/AreaLearningInGameController.cs)) that checks if an existing placed marker (gameobject) is touched during a touch event:

```
        Touch t = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector2 guiPosition = new Vector2(t.position.x, Screen.height - t.position.y);
        Camera cam = Camera.main;
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        if (t.phase != TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (m_selectedRect.Contains(guiPosition))
        {
            // do nothing, the button will handle it
        }
        else if (Physics.Raycast(cam.ScreenPointToRay(t.position), out hitInfo))
        {
            // Found a marker, select it (so long as it isn't disappearing)!
            GameObject tapped = hitInfo.collider.gameObject;
            if (!tapped.GetComponent<Animation>().isPlaying)
            {
                m_selectedMarker = tapped.GetComponent<ARMarker>();
            }
        }
```

What you need is handled by

```
if (Physics.Raycast(cam.ScreenPointToRay(t.position), out hitInfo))
```